# How to supress invalid type for Teradata Insert?

Tags: teradata

When inserting data from one table to another ,  Teradata performs an automatic type cast. So for example if one inserts a `varchar` into a `date` field , `Teradata` will cast the `varchar` to `date`. And this works perfect if all varchars look like valid date strings.

However, when `Teradata` encounters a `varchar` that does not look like a valid `date`, then it is unable to cast , so it shows an error . How can i force a `dirty insert` ?  I want `Teradata` to insert NULL if it's unable to cast (silently ignoring the errors)

Is there any way to do that ?

Comment: Is there only one format for the dates? You need to write a C-UDF checking for a valid date. In TD14 you might also use a regular expression (at least if you don't have to deal with date like 2015-02-30)

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the calendar table.  Some of this will depend on the structure of your data, but basically:

```
insert into <your destination table>
    select
    <t1.columns>,
t2.calendar_date 
    from <your table> t1
    left join sys_calendar.calendar t2
      on t1.<your character date column> = cast (cast(t2.calendar_date as 
        date format 'YYYY-MM-DD') as char(10))
```

The formatting will depend on what your column actually looks like.

Instead of inserting the column from your source table, you would insert calendar_date column from the calendar table.  If the date in your source table is invalid, you'll insert a null.